# Getting value from SPFieldBoolean

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, eventreceiver

How do I get the value from a SPFieldBoolean object? Do I simply cast it to a boolean or do I need to do something further with it?

I am fetching it in an EventReceiver class during an ItemAdded event from `properties.ListItem["fieldname"]`.

If there is a chance the field might not exist (and be null), how do I check for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is already a `bool`, you just need to type-cast it. All fields provide values in their native value-type — see also [SPField.FieldValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.fieldvaluetype%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property that gives you the actual type in case you need to inspect it on runtime.

To make sure the field is contained in the list, just use the [SPFieldCollection.ContainsField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms196070%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method on your list's `Fields` collection.

Comment: It won't let me compile using "bool field = (bool) properties.ListItem["field"]. Do I need to first make a SPFieldBoolean and then type cast from that (or use FieldValueType) ?

Comment: use "bool field = Convert.ToBoolean(properties.ListItem["field"])"